# How can I use gnu make older in configure command?

Tags: makefile, gnu, configure

I want to install a application with commands of "configure", "make" and "make install". This application is needed to gnu make 3.76 or later; but I have fedora core 22 with GNU Make 4.0. When I config with "configure" command; I get the following error:

$ ./configure

...

checking for gmake... /bin/gmake

checking GNU Make 4.0 against constraint... GNU Make version too old!

configure: error: This configure requires version 3.76 or later of gnu make - you have 4.0

$ make --v

GNU Make 4.0

Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

...

$ which make

/usr/bin/make

$

For solving it, I install locally gnu make 3.76.1. The executable file of "make" is located in /home/sn/make-3.76.1. Also I add the following line to .bashrc file:

export PATH=/home/sn/make-3.76.1/:$PATH

After it, I open new terminal and check the version of make that mentioned below:

$ make --v

GNU Make version 3.76.1, by Richard Stallman and Roland McGrath.

...

$ which make

~/make-3.76.1/make

$

At new terminal, I again config but unfortunately, I get error mentioned above. How can I change make used by configure file from GNU make 4.0 to GNU make 3.76.1? What do I use options of configure command?
 Please guide me?
Shahrokh

Comment: Did you run `export PATH=...` in the new terminal window?

Comment: yes, when I add the following line to /home/sn/.bashrc file, I expect to execute "make" that I installed locally. After doing it, when I enter the command of "make --v" in new terminal, I get version number 3.76.1 instead of 4.0 which is installed by default of fedora core 22. Please guide me, I stop in this step of my work.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` in a new terminal say? Is the path to the new make the first? Are there spelling errors? Also you can try `sh -c 'echo $PATH'` as configure scripts typically run /bin/sh as their interpreter and not the login shell.

Comment: @Shahrokh Is there a log file that would provide more information on how the version comparison is actually done?

Comment: Are you **debugging** this configure problem, or just using this software?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe when you configure your application, it used gmake instead of make, so you should make a soft link for your new make to be gmake and have a try.